# If a breaker is GFCI/AFCI protected, does the NEC still require garage and exterior outlets to be GFCI protected?

Tags: receptacle, gfci, nec

I am looking into upgrading the cabling from very old clothed 14-3 wire to 14-3 MC wire and the outlets in my garage and I understand they must be GFCI protected; however, can I simply replace the current breaker that is installed (which is not GFCI protected) to one that is protected and then install normal outlets in the garage or would the NEC code regulations require the outlets be protected regardless of what is upstream.

Comment: NEC has never required GFCI receptacles.  Where GFCI is required, breakers suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The National Electrical Code requires GFCI **protection** in some locations, it does not specify *how* that protection is provided (well... It gives you options on how you can do it). If GFCI protection is provided by a breaker, then the GFCI protection requirement is met.